# ERC20 tokens workflow

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, tokens, erc-20

I am trying to understand what is the "workflow" (for the lack of a better word) of an ERC token in.  Looking at [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0x88fcfbc22c6d3dbaa25af478c578978339bde77a) guy (nothing special about it, just a randon token), I can see that the first sucecssfull transaction on that contract is [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdd3fd9669aaa096f8c34398724a3f1a60f9df2d45fde739f35e1fbefe345ffa1) one where an account (that starts with 3dc) called the Transfer function on contract and transfered 1 token (from its balance I believe) to an account that starts with "1caa". And then several hundred token transfers followed.

Im wondering how did account 0x3dc... have the token in the first place? I have been trought its transactions on etherscan and it never transfered ether to the contract.

Also, am I correct to assume that accounts get tokens by simply making ether transfers to the token's contract them, assuming the contract implement a payable function, the contract will get the ether and then updates the account's token balance on its "balances" variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you described in terms of selling tokens for ether is sometimes done, but it's more common for a token contract to just grant its creator an initial supply of tokens and for everything else to happen based on transfers from the creator. If tokens are to be sold in a crowdsale, it's common to have a second contract that handles the sale.

We have a few relevant posts on [Program the Blockchain](https://programtheblockchain.com) that should help explain the concept:

- [What is an Ethereum Token?](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/26/what-is-an-ethereum-token/)
- [Writing an ERC20 Token Contract](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/)
- [Writing a Token Sale Contract](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/02/writing-a-token-sale-contract/)

**EDIT**

In the token you mentioned, code in the constructor assigns the initial balance to the account that created the contract:

```
function Token( uint initial_balance, address wallet, uint256 crowdsaleTime) {
  _balances[msg.sender] = initial_balance;
  _supply = initial_balance;
  walletAddress = wallet;
  creationTime = crowdsaleTime;
  transferStop = true;
}
```

Comment: yeah that was my understanding. But did u have the chance to take a look at the accounts\transactions I mentioned? The contract code is available on etherscan and nowhere it assigns tokens to acc 0x3dc... neither that account sent ether to the contract. So Im still wondering how did 0x3dc had a token to transfer in the first place?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: yeah but the account that created the contract is not 0x3dc...  look here:
 https://etherscan.io/tx/0x60a564d6e11a9e3c16309d42f8820958e507e1297bf6d5ff9bbd37f24a390a4a

thanks for your help

Comment: I would guess that the `walletAddress` account called `mintTokens`. Some transactions made through contracts (so neither "to" nor "from" the account being viewed) with no ether attached just don't show up on Etherscan.